# How does the shared_ptr's implementation handle custom deleters?

Tags: c++

I know that the shared_ptr's implementation is using type erasure but still being a newb I've not been able to write code to replicate it. In particular I'm not understanding how it handles the function that you pass it via the constructor without storing it and then being able to call it afterwards.

Could somebody show some code of what this implementation's handling of custom deleters may look like and give an in-depth explanation of it?

Comment: You could look at the shared_ptr implementation. It _does_ store the deleter, if you supply one. It has to. There's no other way.

Comment: Why do you assume that it is not stored?

Comment: The deleter is typically stored in the control block (where the reference counter is also stored).

Comment: @n.m. how does the deleter go from the constructor to the control block?

Comment: The constructor gets the deleter as an argument, allocates the control block, and moves the deleter there. What problem do you perceive in this? If in doubt, look at the constructors of __shared_count in libstdc++.

Answer (score -1):

A `std::shared_ptr` stores its `Deleter`. This does not mean though that it has to own it. You can always wrap any invocable type in a reference using `std::ref` or `std::cref`, because `std::reference_wrapper` has a forwarding `operator()` defined. You can use this trick in case your `Deleter` is not copiable.

Comment: This does not answer the question.